# PHP timestamp to HTML 5 input type=datetime element

Tags: php, html, input, timestamp

I have a unix timestamp (int) in PHP. I want to display this value in a nice manner in the HTML5 datetime input element. I would like to be able to have users see this value in a nice presentable manner, as well as edit it. Is there any nice way of doing this, or am I fooling myself and I am going to have to fuss around with lots of string manipulation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HTML5 Input time` is something like this  : [1985-04-12T23:20:50.52](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html)

You can do that in PHP like this :

```
echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s");
```

Output

```
2012-10-02T19:12:49
```

HTML with Timestamp

```
<input type="datetime"  value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",$timestamp); ?>"/>
```

Comment: That will go in the value attribute of the `<input type="datetime" ... />` element? Also, I think you mant `.` not `,`, just so it does not confuse anybody else.

Comment: `echo` allows `,` to separate output.

Comment: And i learned something new today. Thank you for being gracious about my supposed correction.

Comment: Not only is `,` allowed with `echo`, but it's faster than `.`.

Comment: date() is wrong, when you need a specific timezone. use strftime and set timezone.

Comment: This works for me among tens of formation `"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"`

Comment: very nice solution when dealing with html5's native datetime

Answer (score 10):

The other examples are both the old way to produce a valid timeStamp format for the TIME element -- the new hotness in php:

```
<time><?php echo date(DATE_W3C); ?></time>
```

That will generate a format like:

"2013-05-19T06:40:08+00:00"

Comment: The question asks specifically about `input[type=datetime]` *not* `time[datetime]`.

Thank you for introducing me to `date()`'s [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types), though! I will stick to `date('c')` which also results in an identical [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string as well hehe.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [HTML5 Specification for *input type="datetime"*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html), it should be as simple as setting the `value` attribute.

```
value="<?php echo date('c', $timestamp); ?>"
```

See [PHP's date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for additional formatters.

Comment: I want datetime as specified in the question.

Answer (score 3):

**Datetime** doesn't work for me on chrome, **datetime-local** allows me to choose date and time from popup.

example

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="xyz" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",time()); ?>"/>
```

*time() functions is not relevant ,I am using it to make it easy for user to choose from current.. time after or before.*