# Shorthand for HTML5 datetime-local-friendly date format (no timezone)?

Tags: php, datetime, php-7

Is there a quick way to format a [`\DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) into [HTML-friendly Local date and time string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Local_date_and_time_strings) (e.g. `1986-01-28T11:38:00.01`)?

Both [`DATE_W3C`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632120) and [`c`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695125) will produce a timezone, which doesn't work with [`datetime-local`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value).

I know I can do `"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"`, but was curious if there's a slightly more elegant shorthand by now?

Comment: What do you mean with more elegant? isn't it elegant enough that you use datetime->format for that purpose?

Comment: I'm not talking about `format()` itself, I'm talking about the arguments to it. I was looking for a shorthand for `Y-m-d\TH:i:s`, that way it's faster to type and avoids hardcoding the format.

Comment: In that case, you could use one of the constants defined in `\DateTimeInterface`. You are probably looking for something similar to: `(new \DateTime)->format(\DateTimeInterface::ISO8601)`. There is even the `W3C` constant there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the constants defined on the `DateTimeInterface`:

```
const ATOM = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP';
const COOKIE = 'l, d-M-Y H:i:s T';
const ISO8601 = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sO';
const RFC822 = 'D, d M y H:i:s O';
const RFC850 = 'l, d-M-y H:i:s T';
const RFC1036 = 'D, d M y H:i:s O';
const RFC1123 = 'D, d M Y H:i:s O';
const RFC2822 = 'D, d M Y H:i:s O';
const RFC3339 = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP';
const RFC3339_EXTENDED = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP';
const RFC7231 = 'D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T';
const RSS = 'D, d M Y H:i:s O';
const W3C = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sP';
```

Example:

```
(new \DateTime)->format(\DateTimeInterface::W3C)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!